# Org mode export of intraperiodic spaces

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

In LaTeX, I use extra spacing to separate sentences from each other.
This may for instance be achieved by

```
\spaceskip=.33333em plus .16667em  minus .083333em 
\xspaceskip=.8em plus .4em minus .13333em
\nonfrenchspacing
```

With these settings I must take care to make it known when I want to
use a full stop for something other than ending a period, such as
marking an abbreviation.
This I do by typing

```
Mr.\ Charles
```

&c.  But if I write `Mr.\ Charles` in an org buffer and export to
LaTeX, I get a literal `\` in my pdf, which corresponds to `\\` in
the exported source.  How can I get `\` in the source and a normal
space skip in the typeset document?

I know I can do `Mr.@@latex:\@@ Charles`, but is there no better way?

Answer (score 1):

Check the answers to the following question where they discuss this in detail:

[How to make non-breaking spaces (ties) in Org-mode that exports properly to LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311538/how-to-make-non-breaking-spaces-ties-in-org-mode-that-exports-properly-to-late)

They show four different ways to insert a literal space:

```
e.g.~example

e.g. example

#+BEGIN_LaTeX
  e.g.~example
#+END_LaTeX

e.g. example
```

I had the exact same problem handling the space between *Mr.* and the lastname. What worked for me was the suggestion on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311538/how-to-make-non-breaking-spaces-ties-in-org-mode-that-exports-properly-to-late#comment36588321_21936300), because I consider it to be the least visually intrusive.

I just insert **`C-x 8 SPC`** where I want a literal space.

Comment: This risks being deleted as a link-only answer. Please summarize the content that you are linking to, to make your answer say something, itself.

Comment: Thanks Drew, it is my first time answering a question so I don't know the proper etiquette. Let me know if now it is okay, or maybe we can leave a comment with the link to the other answer. I put my answer because I am offering what did work for me when I had the same problem the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that has worked reliably for me was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690064/7678794):

```
e.g.\space{}example
```

After including `(setq org-entities-user '(("space" "\\ " nil " " " " " " " ")))` into my .emacs

I am using Emacs 25.1.1, Org mode 9.0.9 and pdfTeX-1.40.17